# FindBoost.cmake: Use different Compiler-version (vc90 instead of vc100)

Tags: windows, boost, cmake, vc90

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with the `MSVC90` compiler. Because of this I only have Boost for `VC90` installed.

Now I have a Thirdparty-component which is dependant on Boost and which I want to use. This components build system is CMake.

When I try to generate a Visual Studio solution from the given CMake-Script I ran into problems with FindBoost.cmake. It seems as if CMake is guessing that my compiler is `VC100` because I have Visual Studio 2010 installed. I cannot find a CMake-Variable or something like that to manually set the compiler to `VC90`.

I already tried playing around with the Variables `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `BOOST_COMPILER` but had no success.

Is there a way which I hadn't found to let FindBoost.cmake search for the `VC90` libs instead of the `VC100` libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CMake-variable which is called `BOOST_COMPILER`. Set this variable to `-vc90`